# Grouping and present a part of the form as optional

Tags: website-design, web-app, design

I have a "create project" screen. Here the user may choose to add members to his project. I.e adding members is optional and can be added later too. But i want to present him an option to do and start too.

I am unable to properly group the members part, and present in a way where the user can easily understand that this can be skipped.

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try showing only a link/button at first. Clicking on it will show the members input and move the focus on it.

[image]

(somewhat related, you could allow users to add multiple members at once by separating them with a comma)

Comment: This looks nice. But i also wanted to show in this case to the current user that he is added to the project already or there is no point in showing that ?

Comment: you could show the current user is already added, maybe with some explanation on why it's already there. not sure about the remove button for it though; what happens if you remove yourself and there's no other admin?

Comment: Yes yes, that got added by copy paste.. The creater of the project cannot leave unless theres another admin to the project. Thanks for your answer and replies.

Comment: M also thinking of dividing the page into teo halves and putting the add member on right side wid a default opacity which would be removed on hover and the control would be enabled for that. And use the same screen in section by section edit mode later on. Your thoughts ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FDaPQDf.png my changes.

Comment: looks ok, but you have to keep in mind that you picked the ideal case where it's only one user in the right column. if you have 2-3 more, it will overpower the left column which has, after all, the main action of this screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a question of marking the required and optional fields better. Also: the title 'members' needs to be phrased 'add members' since this is what the user will be doing.

here's a comp:

[image]